# Typescript: Access properties of Sub class from Base class setter

Tags: node.js, typescript, inheritance

I have a subclass Employee and a Base class Person.
In the constructor of the Person class, I call the setter function that sets the attributes after some validation.
But in the setter function I cannot get the properties of Employee Class.

```
//Employee.ts
import Person from "./Person"
class Employee extends Person {
    empID: string = '';
    designation: string = '';

    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
    }
}

let obj = {empID:123,designation:"developer",firstName:"John",lastName:"Doe"}
let employee: Employee = new Employee(obj)

//Person.ts
export default class Person {
    firstName: string = '';

    lastName: string = '';

    constructor (props:object) {
        this.props = props
    }

    set props(props:object) {
        console.log("this",this)
        /***************prints Employee { firstName: '', lastName: '' } cannot access empID and designation  **********/
        for (const f in props) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(f)) {
                this[f] = props[f]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this works

```
//Employee.ts
import Person from "./Person"
class Employee extends Person {
    empID: string = '';
    designation: string = '';

    constructor () {
        super();
    }
}

let obj = {empID:123,designation:"developer",firstName:"John",lastName:"Doe"}
let employee: Employee = new Employee()
employee.props = obj

//Person.ts
export default class Person {
    firstName: string = '';

    lastName: string = '';

    constructor () {

    }

    set props(props:object) {
        console.log("this",this)
        /***************prints Employee { firstName: '', lastName: '', empID: '', designation: '' }  **********/
        for (const f in props) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(f)) {
                this[f] = props[f]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong in the first example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: JavaScript allows all sort of crazy things since it is dynamic, but access a subclass from a base class would completely break OO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `super` the subclass is not initialized yet. You can set `props` right after `super` call:

```
constructor (props) {
    super();
    this.props = props;
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKCmAnCB7AdtA3gKGn6AZgJbIAuAcmALbwBc0EpiRaA5tALzQDk3A3LnzhGlGvUbM2nHv2yC8wdBICuwUikQAKAJRZ50AL5z8DeKWgAHRCgsRNVmxHooARgCt4a3ThMnFaVBB4ADoQFFZNACJSAAsiCEiAGmhY+O19EwINaE1-RkJoFktrW28M3zwiAhzUiGCYyAB5AHc0WBKkUgBPTQJtMorB-FqAbQIAXWkHWzHx8oqjIcX8IyNsUEgYAFEqCzCu+HhoeAAPUng0ABMYBGR0PRN4XYBJABFxJhZ2Ll4BE0v4BAiKw0GBSER0B9JN8ZAJ9HkmKp1FpphABoMIMoLEgdH9BrVgqipiUIHi8Ks5Gh4M1oDs9igDvBNJhji93tAAIwAJgAzMkAUCQWCIWh6JEAQA3eBhbGIJKEEgiah0aCRABSKBiaHlwgoyrFrxQ8Eihm0QA)

Comment: On line 12 this[f] = props[f]
There is an error 
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'Person'.No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'Person.
Do you how to fix that as well?

Comment: @Sarita You can try to define a type guard, but in this specific case I'd just `// @ts-ignore` the error